# How can I encode long-form mp3 files so that they do not stop and reset at random positions in the audio?

Tags: android, encoding, mp3, reset

I have this situation where mp3's I encode with iTunes, FFmpeg, or LAME all have a problem where if you stream them to an Android device, they will almost always stop playing at about the 15-25 minute mark. When I press play again, it resets back to the beginning.

What I am looking for is a solution that can be implemented purely in the encoding. It may be a software bug with Android's stock audio player, but I have little control over that.

The mp3's are generally about 45 minutes. I encode them at 64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, and Stereo. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is your server sending the correct Content-Type header? It should be `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: Late reply, sorry. Yes, we have the Content-Type set as audio/mpeg. We've basically just wrote it off as a bug in the Android 2.x audio player because it's happening for all of our clients inside and outside of the apps they have with us.